# i send request to the wordpress rest api to get token and i get strange callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-networking, wordpress-rest-api

I want to login user from android app to wordpress , so i send request to the server but it seems it's not successful

my User.java contain getters and setters for email id token.

Login.java

```
 private String email,password;
    public Login (String email,String password){
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
    }
```

RetroFitInterface.java

```
@POST ("Authorization: Bearer")
    Call<User> login (@Body Login login);
```

MainActivity.java

```
Retrofit.Builder builder=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://taqoh.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
Retrofit retrofit=builder.build();
RetroFitInterface retroFitInterface=retrofit.create(RetroFitInterface.class);
private Button button,button1;

private static String token;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 button=findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
 button1=findViewById(R.id.get_token_btn);
 button.setOnClickListener(this);
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
private void login(){
    Login login=new Login("email@something.com","secret-password");
    Call<User>call=retroFitInterface.login(login);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("requestwp",response.message());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               token=response.body().getToken();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("requestwp",t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

i get callback message from onfailure:
  malformed URL base:https://taqoh.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/,relative 
  Authorization: Bearer

Comment: it shows [Error 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) check if url is proper

Comment: @Ashish according to https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth this is the end point i should send request to

Comment: am i sending the request correctly?

Comment: @Mistart the `,` comma in your url is strange?

Comment: i see it's post req and he is sending it wrong url